# Moodle: Installation failed - Coding Error Detected

Tags: mysql, apache, moodle

I have tried to install Moodle 3.5.1 on my development server `(Apache 2.4.29 and MySQL v.5.7).`

The installation process went smoothly: The MySQL database has been set up, all required PHP packages are installed, the system has been successfully installed, all file permissions are correct.

After the installation I only get the following error:

```
"Coding error detected, it must be fixed by a programmer: PHP catchable fatal error"
```

There are no further error messages. There are no error messages in Apache Error log or PHP log files. In the PHP ini file the display of error messages is activated.

So I can not figure out what did not work or how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Put `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` in the beggining of the script you see problem in for more debug info

Comment: Thank you, but I had already done that. Unfortunately, no further error messages are displayed.

Comment: Add it after all requires and includes

Answer (score 0):

Moodle 3.5 requires PHP 7

https://docs.moodle.org/35/en/PHP

Could that be your problem?